# Input line in terminal has changed

Tags: macos, terminal

Maybe the formulation of the problem is not quite good, but I don't really know how to call this line:

```
se-178:/ mityakoval$
```

I'm using MacOS X. And the problem is, that this input line used to look like this:

```
mityakoval:/ mityakoval$
```

And at some point after manipulations with installing wordpress, configuring Apache server and MySQL, it has turned to this:

```
se-178:/ mityakoval$
```

I don't really know who or what is `se-178`, but I'm really afraid if had done something bad to the OS. Don't you know why did it change itself?

Thanks

Comment: When you are in terminal what is the output if you do the command `hostname`? And what is the output of the command `echo $PS1`?

Comment: @prodigitalson 
`hostname` – `mityakoval.local`
`echo $PS1` – `\h:\W \u\$`

Comment: Hmmm thats really wierd your looks like `\h` outputting an incorrect hostname - for some reason it thinks its `se-178`. is `mityakoval` also in Prefercences.app > Sharing > Computer Name?

Comment: @prodigitalson `mityakoval` is also in Computer Name. I assume it always happens when there are some errors in mysql. I do something in mysql, of course there are some errors, but when I exit mysql there appears something like `se-178`. It turns back to `mityakoval` at some point (after restart, for example). Now it's `client-83-181`. and when I do `hostname` it says `client-83-181.wireless.hig.no`. `echo $PS1` still gives me `\h:\W \u\$`. thank you for your help :)

Comment: Thats really odd... are you using ssh to log in to another box or VM for something?

Comment: @prodigitalson nope. nothing like that.